# JusPay Helper redirect to new activity after payment

Tags: android

JusPay Helper android,

Once i hit the payment button, it is getting redirected to the JusPay payment browser. After payment it is getting redirected to the parent activity. But i want it be redirected to another new activity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: make use of endUrlRegexes and endUrlReached if it matches then call new activity

Comment: thanks ill try it..